# Please tell me how to stop continuous searching in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Once I run search all using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> then my search does not stop, and it is showing searching in the status panel.

How do I stop this? I am using Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Did you know... How to stop a find in files search? - #080](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2007/11/09/did-you-know-how-to-stop-a-find-in-files-search-080/)

This site always has very handy tips/tricks.

Comment: Shouldn't direct someone to a link to read the answer. Post the answer without requiring me to go to a link.

Answer (score 19):

Use Ctrl+Shift+F again, you should see the "Find All" button now becomes "Stop".

Or you can click the 'Stop Searching' button on the toolbar of the 'Find Result' panel.

Comment: yes their is button of 'stop searching' but its not working.. i mean i have clicked on that button and closed find but my searching not got stopped and when i again did ctrl+shift+f its showing again stop button...so button is their but its not stopping search

Comment: Yes, it is a serious issue. Especially if I do a search using regular expression in the entire solution, it just keeps on searching and searching and there is no way to stop it. The VS team should really fix this.

Comment: This worked for me. Note that the search isn't halted immediately, it takes a few seconds. After that time though, the results completed are shown, along with `Find was stopped in progress.`

Comment: 13 years later and this search bug still exists in VS2017.  Just be sure to save your work regularly and then go to TaskManager and cancel the VS process.  I get this about once a week and drives me bonkers (even tried waiting - it was stuck for 3 hours, so I killed the task and restarted VS)